# List values on a schedule based on time and date

Tags: excel

I have a collection of raw data stored in a table using headings of

```
1. Name, String             //Name of employee
2. Job, String              //The job site they are on
3. Start Date (SD), Date    //Starting date
4. End Date (ED), Date      //Ending date
5. Start Time(ST), Time     //Start time each day
6. End Time (ET), Time      //End time each day
7. Saturday, Bool           //Whether they will be onsite on Saturday
8. Sunday, Bool             //Same as above
```

In an excel sheet, I have a table formatted as such

[Raw data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFnDS.png)

[Working Schedule Spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DEatm.png)

In each cell, I currently have this array entered formula

```
=IFNA(INDEX(INDIRECT(Cells!$B$2), MATCH(1, ($A3 = INDIRECT(Cells!$A$2)) * (C$1 >= INDIRECT(Cells!$C$2)) * (C$1 < INDIRECT(Cells!$D$2)) * ($B3 >= INDIRECT(Cells!$E$2)) * ($B3 < INDIRECT(Cells!$F$2)), 0)), "")
//The INDIRECT references the input table
```

This currently works, but doesn't check if the employee is scheduled on for Sat or Sun (which default to false). The way it works is by doing a multivariable index-match on all of the variables listed. I cannot figure out how I might be able to also include the boolean bit.

The issue I am having is that if I add `(TEXT(C$2, "ddd") = INDIRECT(Cells!$G$2))` into the match, then it will only work if it is *on* a Saturday, so having a similar statement to check for Sundays won't show at all.

[Broken Schedule Spreadsheet using second formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRugd.png)

I hope that makes sense, I can supply more information if needed. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a couple of conditionals.

```
=IFNA(INDEX(INDIRECT(Cells!$B$2),MATCH(1,($A3=INDIRECT(Cells!$A$2))*(C$1>=INDIRECT(Cells!$C$2))*(C$1<INDIRECT(Cells!$D$2))*($B3>=INDIRECT(Cells!$E$2))*($B3<INDIRECT(Cells!$F$2))*IF(WEEKDAY(F$1)=7,INDIRECT(Cells!$G$2),1)*IF(WEEKDAY(F$1)=1,INDIRECT(Cells!$H$2),1),0)),"")
```

Comment: Perfect, I just had to change the Weekday() = 6/7 to 7/1 since Sunday is apparently the first day of the week in Excel. Thanks

Comment: Yeah that's exactly it. Works like a charm. Thanks :)